# ALTER DATABASE [...] SET SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT waits 20 seconds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

On SQL Server 2012, when I am issuing a statement

```
ALTER DATABASE [...] SET SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT
```

and someone else is using the database, I have to wait for approximately 20 seconds until the request fails, despite the NO_WAIT termination clause.

Is it possible to tell SQL Server to let the "ALTER DATABASE" request fail immediately? Preferrably also for older versions of SQL Server? (although it seems that "ALTER DATABASE [...] SET" is not supported in SQL Server 2005 and earlier).

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding... you want the `ALTER DATABASE` statement to fail if there are open transactions on the db, right?  (Otherwise, you should use `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE'.)

Comment: @DMason Yes, that's correct, I want ALTER DATABASE to fail.

Comment: I don't know of a built-in way to get around that 20 second lag time.  Maybe you can query `dm_tran_database_transactions` for open transactions before running `ALTER DATABASE...`

Comment: @DMason Thanks for the suggestion, however there might be some other client simply "sitting" on the database (by having issued a "use <database>" statement). As far as I understand, there wouldn't be a transaction going on in such a case.

Comment: So if a user has an open connection to the db, you want to leave the db in `MULTI_USER` mode (whether there are uncommitted transactions or not)?

Comment: @DMason Yes, that's right. I am fine if anything causes my ALTER DATABASE to fail for any reason, but I want to know about the problem right away. If I can control the wait time that would be even nicer, but 20 seconds wait time is definitely too long for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try.  It checks for active connections to the database before trying to put it into `SINGLE_USER` mode.

```
use master
GO

DECLARE @DBName SYSNAME = N'YourDbName'

IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT sd.Name, sp.*
    FROM sys.sysprocesses sp
    JOIN sys.sysdatabases sd
        ON sd.dbid = sp.dbid
    WHERE sd.Name = @DBName
    AND sp.spid <> @@SPID
)
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [...] 
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT
END
```

Comment: That might be a start. However: `ALTER DATABASE` works if my own connection is the only one that is active on the database. In your proposal, the `SELECT` query would return a row, hence the `ALTER DATABASE` statement would never be issued. Is it possible to refine the `SELECT` so that it excludes my own connection?

Comment: You are correct.  It should be run from a different database.  I've edited the answer with a `user master` statement at the top.

Comment: Also, this will exclude your connection:  `AND sp.spid <> @@SPID`

Comment: Nice! Excluding my connection is important because if I am not connected to the database myself, there is a small time frame where someone else could connect to the database after I have put it into `SINGLE_USER` mode. Anyway, give me some time for playing around with your answer before I accept it. Maybe someone else can conjure up a slightly simpler solution :-)